# C# XML Deserialization from desired XML

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I am attempting to deserialize XML into a usable object graph. I want to make the XML as human writable as possible as it will be a while before we have a tool capable of generating the object structure in our system.

What I am looking for is XML that looks like this

```
<RuleSet>
  <Conditions>
    <AttributeEqualTo>
      <Id>C1</Id>
      <AttributeName>Foo</AttributeName>
      <ExpectedValue>Bar</ExpectedValue>
    </AttributeEqualTo>
    <AttributeNotEqualTo>
      <Id>C2</Id>
      <AttributeName>Blah</AttributeName>
      <ExpectedValue>Value</ExpectedValue>
    </AttributeNotEqualTo>
  </Conditions>
  <States>
    <State>
      <Id>Start</Id>
      <Transitions>
        <Transition>
            <Condition>C1</Condition>
            <State>S1</State>
        </Transition>
        <Transition>
            <Condition>C2</Condition>
            <State>S2</State>
        </Transition>
      </Transitions>
    </State>
    <State>
      <Id>S1</Id>
      <Transitions>
        <Transition>
            <Condition>C2</Condition>
            <State>S2</State>
        </Transition>
      </Transitions>
    </State>
    <State>
      <Id>S2</Id>
    </State>
  </States>
</RuleSet>
```

What I am looking for is an object graph that contains a RuleSet object with an Enumerable of Conditions and an Enumerble of States. Each State will have an Enumerable of Transitions that are made of a condition defined previously, in the RuleSet's conditions, and another state.

Is there a simple way to do this given a n XML parser in C# that someone has already written, instead of having to write our own custom one?

From the initial responses I think I needed to add a bit more clarity. When I tried serializing a simple version of our object graph, with the setting to maintain references turned on to reduce duplication. I received the following:

```
<RuleSet z:Id="1" >
    <Conditions z:Id="2" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <a:anyType z:Id="3" i:type="b:AttributeEqualTo" >
            <b:AttributeName z:Id="4">Foo</b:AttributeName>
            <b:ExpectedValue z:Id="5" i:type="c:string" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">Bar</b:ExpectedValue>
            <b:Id z:Id="6">C1</b:Id>
        </a:anyType>
        <a:anyType z:Id="7" i:type="b:AttributeEqualTo" >
            <b:AttributeName z:Ref="5" i:nil="true"/>
            <b:ExpectedValue z:Ref="4" i:nil="true"/>
            <b:Id z:Id="8">C2</b:Id>
        </a:anyType>
    </Conditions>
    <States z:Id="9" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <a:anyType z:Id="10" i:type="b:State" >
            <b:EntryActions z:Id="11"/>
            <b:Id z:Id="12">S1</b:Id>
            <b:Transitions z:Id="13" z:Size="2">
                <a:anyType z:Id="14" i:type="c:Transition" >
                    <c:Condition z:Ref="3" i:nil="true"/>
                    <c:Next z:Id="15" i:type="b:State">
                        <b:EntryActions z:Id="16"/>
                        <b:Id z:Id="17">S2</b:Id>
                        <b:Transitions z:Id="18" z:Size="1">
                            <a:anyType z:Id="19" i:type="c:Transition">
                                <c:Condition z:Ref="7" i:nil="true"/>
                                <c:Next z:Id="20" i:type="b:State">
                                    <b:EntryActions z:Id="21"/>
                                    <b:Id z:Id="22">S3</b:Id>
                                    <b:Transitions z:Id="23" z:Size="0"/>
                                </c:Next>
                            </a:anyType>
                        </b:Transitions>
                    </c:Next>
                </a:anyType>
                <a:anyType z:Id="24" i:type="c:Transition" >
                    <c:Condition z:Ref="7" i:nil="true"/>
                    <c:Next z:Ref="20" i:nil="true"/>
                </a:anyType>
            </b:Transitions>
        </a:anyType>
        <a:anyType z:Ref="15" i:nil="true"/>
        <a:anyType z:Ref="20" i:nil="true"/>
    </States>
</RuleSet>
```

What I am trying to do is replace the z:Id="x" and z:Ref="x" with usages of my own Id properties. Again to make the system more human writable. I see how to change the names of the tags by setting the attributes in the C# classes.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write your own parser. You can apply Xml serialization attributes to your classes, which will control serialization and deserialization process. Or you can use existing parser, like Linq to Xml.

Here is an example of [Xml serialization attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) usage:

```
public class RuleSet
{
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(AttributeEqualTo))]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(AttributeNotEqualTo))]
    public List<Condition> Conditions { get; set; }
}

public class Condition
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string AttributeName { get; set; }
    public string ExpectedValue { get; set; }
}

public class AttributeEqualTo : Condition
{
    // code
}

public class AttributeNotEqualTo : Condition
{
    // code
}
```

And deserialization:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RuleSet));
RuleSet ruleSet = (RuleSet)serializer.Deserialize(stream_with_xml);
```

Use same approach to deserialize states.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) for this.
Also, given that you don't have any XML attributes in your desired XML, you cauld also use the [NetDataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.netdatacontractserializer.aspx) (the DataContractSerializer does not support the emitting of attributes - only elements).

Either way, you will probably need to annotate your C# classes with attributes (XmlAttributes, or DataMember attributes) to get it to serialize precisely as you need.

Comment: The problem I have had with the DataContractSerializer is the only way to get it to use the references is if you use the id and ref attributes sequentially. I want to use the Id elements to define this.

Comment: @Matt. Okay I get it. If I were you I'd use the DataContractSerializer for this. The example you have at the top of the question has no attributes, just elements so you don't need the XmlSerializer. And by this I mean, model a set of classes that represent your desired object hierarchy then decorate them with the appropriate attributes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your object to be (de)serialized is either a class or a struct. You will need a using statement including System.Xml and System.Xml.Serialization (off the top of my head).

Then you have to decorate this class/struct declaration with the [Serializable] attribute.
Decorate each public property and method that you want to be (de)serialized with its corresponding attribute such as [XmlElement] if you want it to serialize as XML element or [XmlAttribute] if you want it to be an XML attribute of your serialized class/struct.

Also make sure your class has a parameterless constructor or serialization will fail.

And last but not least, use the XmlSerializer/XmlDeserializer to generate/parse. The days of writing custom XML parsing are gone, this is most definitely a HUGE time saver.

Comment: I know we shouldn't have to use a custom parser, and how to get the system to see the schema and such. The problem is getting it to use the referencing system that I am looking to do. (Using the Id properties from the objects instead of a custom attribute.)